# JFilechooser works in eclipse windows but doesn't works on eclipse mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jfilechooser

I am coding a bit huge program on windows platform but now I moved my project on mac.In both platforms I used eclipse but JFilechooser doesn't works on my mac!!

My JFilechooser Function:

```
protected Shell shlGui;
Button btnOpen = new Button(shlGui, SWT.NONE);
    btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(ActionEvent e) {

          JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
              if(jfc.showOpenDialog(jfc) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    //get selected file name [i.e., complete file path]
                  java.io.File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                    txt_open.setText(f.toString());
                    file_path = f.toString();

                    image_resize(lbl_image, f.toString());                                  

                    lbl_image.setImage(new Image(display, "saved.png"));;

                }

    }
        });
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: JFilechooser doesn't works at all once I press btnOpen Button the whole program freeze

Comment: What happens if you use `jfc.showOpenDialog(null)`?